# Rebooting server with MQTT service

Tags: mqtt, iot

Imagine an MQTT broker with remote clients connected, which continuously send QoS 2 data - the standard situation. Clients are configured with "cleansession false" - they have a queue to send messages in case of a connection failure.

On the server, local clients subscribe to topics to receive messages.

Server load:

1. Launch the MQTT Broker
2. Running local clients
3. Connecting remote clients and receiving data from the queue

What if the third point occurs before the second? Are there standard solutions? How not to lose the first messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about all later reboots of the broker, not the very first time the system is started up then the broker should have stored the persistent subscription state of the clients to disk before it was shutdown and restored this when it restarted. This means that it should queue messages for the local clients.

Also you can always use a firewall to stop the remote client being able to connect until all the local clients have started, this would solve the very first startup issue as well.